# XCode Core Data Model - How to update data based on new Model Version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model

On an XCode iOS project, when adding a new version of the data model, and making some structural changes, I need to set some fields based on the current data.

For example, on the original model (version 14) I have the following column:

```
column uniformity Integer 16
```

On the new model (version 15), I added the following columns:

```
column uniformity1 Boolean
column uniformity2 Boolean
```

I need to update these columns so that uniformity1=true if uniformity=1, uniformity2=true if uniformity=1, etc.

Could someone point me in the right direction to achieve this?  Thanks.

Comment: Look up Core Data Migrations.  It feels like yours needs to be a manual one because there's no automatic way for CoreData to do that one for you.

Comment: Here's a [starting point](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145860/core-data-migrations-tutorial-lightweight-migrations-2) for learning about migrations

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that I have to do a manual migration but I haven't found any useful examples or documentation.